# Missing <sub> tags in tex4ht output

Tags: html, tex4ht, subscripts

When processing a LaTeX source with tex4ht, I can't seem to reliably convert subscripts in text mode to `<sub>` tags in the HTML output. My only solution so far is to switch to math mode. But for some reason, if I define the same math code as a macro with `\newcommand` (to avoid typos when typing long math expressions), the `<sub>` tags are gone again!

Example source:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{subscript}
\newcommand{\tsub}{$a_b$}
\begin{document}
x\textsuperscript{n}
y\textsubscript{1}
$a_b$
\tsub{}
\end{document}
```

... which I process using:

```
htlatex example.tex 'html, charset=utf-8' ' -cunihtf -utf8'
```

Is there an easy way to make tex4ht honor `\textsubscript` or `$_{}$` commands in `\newcommand` macros?

Thanks for any suggestion,

--Mathieu

Comment: Thanks **michal.h21**, that did most of the trick. `\newcommand{\foo}{$foo_{bar}$}` still fails silently, but `\newcommand{\foo}{foo\textsubscript{bar}}` fulfills my needs.

Comment: Also, I don't know if there is something I should do to tag the question as solved (upvoting requires more reputation than I have)...

Comment: yeah, version with math environment seems little bit hackish to me, in text is `\textsubscipt` much better

Comment: accepting suffices, but you can try also upvoting, I think you have enough reputation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems there is no configuration for `subscript` package, so you must create one. Configurations for packages are stored in files with extension `.4ht`, so for `subscript` create `subscript.4ht`:

```
\NewConfigure{textsubscript}{2}
\renewcommand\textsubscript[1]{%
\a:textsubscript#1\b:textsubscript
}
\Configure{textsubscript}{\Tg<sub>}{\Tg</sub>}
```

This file will be automatically  loaded by `tex4ht` when you call `\usepackage{subscript}`